# Plot dynamic Nvd3 chart without reinitialising?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm creating a pie chart:

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.key;   })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .valueFormat(d3.format(',d'))
        .labelsOutside(true)
        .showLabels(true);
```

and then I'm retrieving some data repeatedly via AJAX and updating the chart:

```
(function loop() {
    d3.json(url, function(data) {
        d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);
    });
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
})();
```

However, if I uncheck one of the values in the legend to remove an entry it always reappears at the next timer refresh, causing that slice to reappear.

Is there a way to just refresh the data without causing it to reinitialise?  I've tried using `.data` instead of `.datum` to no avail.

Comment: I don't think there is without modifying the source code. In your update function you could also simulate a "click" on the legend items that have been deselected to deselect them again after initialisation.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff do you think that's an nvd3 limitation or in d3 itself?

Comment: NVD3. If you code this yourself in D3 you won't have the problem.